# Why do we select 'Time zone' twice in JasperReports Server (v6.2) scheduling

Tags: quartz-scheduler, scheduling, jasperserver

I could see that 'Time zone' is selected in both 'schedule' tab and 'output options' tab of JasperReports Server scheduler.

So, please clarify what is the use of selecting "Time zone" again under 'output options' tab of a Jasperserver even though we specified the Time zone under 'schedule' tab.

Also, can we remove/ignore 'Time zone' option under 'output options' tab?

Answer (score 1):

This can be of use if your company or your customers are set up internationally.

**Schedule time zone**

This time zone is the zone which is being used to calculate correctly, at which hour the report should be generated. This is only used for the schedule of the generation. So one could set the generation time for a few countries to 8:00 in the morning just by selecting the correct time zone.

**Output time zone**

With this time zone you can set the report time zone. This means the calculation of time and date values can be changed separately for every reciepient. So for example the Europe office would get their share of data interpreted with `Europe/Berlin` and the asia office with settings for `Asia/Malaysia`. All times and dates will be set according to the time zone.

Comment: Thanks for your response tobi6. To maintain same Database timing for all the schedule reports, can I remove/hide this Time zone selection option from the 'output options' tab of JRS scheduling?

Comment: There is no configuration option for the scheduler page that I am aware of. If my (or another answer) helped you out, consider marking it as answered ([How to mark question as answered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow)).